# How to pass a function with a parameter without calling it

Tags: javascript, function, button, parameters, onclick

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find an answer, or at least one I can understand at my very limited skill level (I'm essentially teaching myself html, css, and js with practice and Google). I am trying to use `document.getElementById("button").onclick = buttonfunc;` as part of a function with `buttonfunc` as a parameter. I've been able to call this function easily enough with something equivalent to `Buttons(MyFunction);`, because if I put the parentheses like `Buttons(MyFunction());` my understanding is that it treats the parameter as the value of `MyFunction()`, even though it's a void function. The problem with this is that I can't pass parameters with the function, meaning I have to make a new function for every new thing I want a button to do, which I would like to avoid if I can because there might be very mundane or similar function. Is there a way to pass a parameter with the function so that I don't have to make a new one for every minute difference? Thanks in advance!

Here is the full code of the function and some examples of its use (I'm making a text adventure with 8 buttons).

```js
function Buttons(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b1func, b2func, b3func, b4func, b5func, b6func, b7func, b8func) {
    if (b1func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = b1;
        document.getElementById("b1").onclick = b1func;
    }
    if (b2func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = b2;
        document.getElementById("b2").onclick = b2func;
    }
    if (b3func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b3").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = b3;
        document.getElementById("b3").onclick = b3func;
    }
    if (b4func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b4").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b4").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML = b4;
        document.getElementById("b4").onclick = b4func;
    }
    if (b5func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b5").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b5").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML = b5;
        document.getElementById("b5").onclick = b5func;
    }
    if (b6func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b6").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b6").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML = b6;
        document.getElementById("b6").onclick = b6func;
    }
    if (b7func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b7").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b7").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML = b7;
        document.getElementById("b7").onclick = b7func;
    }
    if (b8func == 0) {
        document.getElementById("b8").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("b8").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML = b8;
        document.getElementById("b8").onclick = b8func;
    }
}

Buttons("Male", "Female", "Neutral (it pronouns)", "Neutral (they pronouns)", "", "", "", "", He, She, It, They, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Buttons(
        "Citizen<span class=\"tooltip\">You are the winner of an essay-writing contest, earning a funded trip to the cosmos on the condition you keep a journal of your experience to be published at the conclusion of your journey. You will start at iDune, the Intragalactic Diplomatic post of the United Nations of Earth.</span>",
        "Diplomat<span class=\"tooltip\">You are a diplomat sent to Armistice, a city-planet and the political hub of the galaxy. You are representing the United Nations of Earth, playing a very minor role in increasing the human population at Armistice and creating positive first impressions among its citizens.</span>",
        "Explorer<span class=\"tooltip\">You are an opportunist, ready to explore planetary systems that have yet to be mapped, and hopefully find valuable resources or phenomena to be claimed, patented, or profited from. You will start at Tenkets, a commercial hub and massive market satellite established by the shelish.</span>",
        "Merchant<span class=\"tooltip\">You are a vendor of goods from Earth, ready to spread new commodities to the alien races for a price. What goods you sell, and their legality, is up to you. You will start in Menagerie, a cultural hub planet and allegedly the most diverse place in the galaxy.</span>",
        "Spacer<span class=\"tooltip\">You are a member of the United Nations of Earth's Interstellar Defense Force, the servicemen and women of which are known as \"spacers\". You are currently on a survey ship, working with a small squad to protect its crew as they investigate UNE interests.</span>",
        "Stowaway<span class=\"tooltip\">You are a criminal stowed away on a ship leaving Earth. You have little to your name and no idea where the ship you are in is headed, nor do you know whether you will be able to safely disembark without getting caught.</span>",
        "", "", Citizen, Diplomat, Explorer, Merchant, Spacer, Stowaway, 0, 0);

Buttons("Yes<span class=\"tooltip\">Continue with the selected start.</span>", "No<span class=\"tooltip\">Restart character creation.</span>", "", "", "", "", "", "", Start, CharacterCreation, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here or what the problem is, exactly, but it looks like you could use a loop to avoid all of the repetition. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and perhaps think about posing your question about the problem X rather than your attempted solution Y.

Comment: Any time you have more than about 3 parameters to a function, you should stop and think "is there a better way?" When you have as many as you have here, then you should *know* there's got to be a better way - even if you can't see what it is yet.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for the welcome! The problem is I'm trying to pass a function as a parameter, which I've found success in, but I can't figure out how to pass a parameter along with that function. I apologize if I went again a standard convention, I was just trying to elaborate on what I have been trying and the context of the problem 

Comment: The basic idea is to wrap the call in an anonymous function: `.onclick = function () { MyFunction(param); };`

Comment: @RobinZigmond I am certain there is, and I would love to learn of it! I'm only just starting out, so unfortunately this is the best way I've figured out how to do it 

Comment: @ChrisG That did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.bind` method.

```js
const myFunctionWithParameters = myFunction.bind(null, myParameter, myOtherParameter);

myFunctionWithParameters();
// the above line is equivalent to the below line (unless myFunction uses the this variable)
myFunction(myParameter, myOtherParameter);
```

For example:

```js
const sayHello = console.log.bind(null, 'hello');

sayHello();

// this is the same as:

console.log('hello');
```

Comment: This works perfectly! @Chris G suggested putting it in `function{Myfunc(param)}`, is there an advantage one way or another?

Comment: The short answer is:  No.  Not for the way you're using it.  But it can be written simpler as: `() => MyFunc(param)`.  If you like my answer feel free to award me Best Answer by clicking the green checkmark at the top left of my post.

Comment: I think I'll be using bind because it's a bit more readable for me and better conforms to my own like mental logic, if that makes sense. Thanks for the help!